# Не работает USSD запрос

Tags: android, ussd

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. На версии андроид 4.2 не работает отправка USSD запросов. Есть предположение, что неправильно парсится номер приложением для набора номеров. При этом, код, приведенный ниже, нормально работает на версиях ниже и выше. Может быть, кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Вот код:

```
final String ussd = "*100*1";
final String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
final Intent ussdIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
ussdIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd + encodedHash));
mActivity.startActivity(ussdIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Просмотрите вот эти статьи на хабре [USSD в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130717/) и вот этот [Простой USSD-запрос в Android 4.0+](http://habrahabr.ru/post/234425/)

Также в сети есть статья (Правда старая) по роботе с ussd - [Как обрабатывать в Андроиде USSD/MMI запросы](http://commandus.com/blog/?p=58). Также посмотрите вот этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148952/using-iextendednetworkservice-to-get-ussd-response-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top). На гитхабе есть [сорцы](https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor) по работе с USSD запросами. Ну и если очень хочется, а ссылки выше ничем не помогли, тогда попробуйте разобрать готовые приложения под андроид: [Quiet Balance](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melkote.quietbalance) - Работает с версией Андроид 1.6 и выше. [USSD Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.paco.ussd) - начиная с 4.1.